# nginx cache directory doesn't work in windows

Tags: caching, nginx

I've configured nginx as a reverse proxy and to cache content. I've successfully configured it as a reverse proxy to my springboot app. But, it doesn't cache any content rendered from springboot and I'm seeing logs in `error.log` file.

Below is the `nginx.conf` file :

```
http {

    proxy_cache_path  C:\nginx\data\nginx\cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my-cache:8m max_size=1000m inactive=600m;
    proxy_temp_path C:\nginx\data\nginx\tmp;
    inactive=24h  max_size=1g;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;     

        location / {
        # Backend server to forward requests to/from
        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_cache my-cache;
        proxy_cache_valid  200 302  60m;
        proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
     }
  }

}
```

Have tried with multiple `proxy_cache_path` options including `data/nginx/cache`, `\data\nginx\cache` and `C:/nginx/data/nginx/cache`. But, none of them worked in fact, they weren't allowing to stop/start nginx.

Below are the errors observed in nginx `error.log` file :

```
2017/04/21 11:28:07 [emerg] 6352#528: CreateDirectory() "C:\nginx/\data\nginx\cache" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified)
2017/04/21 11:28:53 [notice] 5748#6748: signal process started
2017/04/21 11:28:53 [emerg] 6352#528: CreateDirectory() "C:\nginx/data/nginx/cache" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified)
2017/04/21 11:30:41 [notice] 5244#6032: signal process started
2017/04/21 11:30:41 [emerg] 6352#528: CreateDirectory() "C:
ginx\data
ginx\cache" failed (123: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
2017/04/21 11:31:41 [notice] 6716#5140: signal process started
2017/04/21 11:31:41 [emerg] 6352#528: CreateDirectory() "C:
ginx\data
ginx\cache" failed (123: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
2017/04/21 11:41:23 [crit] 6496#7100: *241 CreateFile() "C:\nginx/data/nginx/tmp/0000000003" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified) while reading upstream, client: 172.23.66.69, server: localhost, request: "GET /js/splunkbar.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/splunkbar.js", host: "vi-dvw70765", referrer: "http://vi-dvw70765/checksplunk/13"
2017/04/21 11:41:25 [crit] 6496#7100: *245 CreateFile() "C:\nginx/data/nginx/tmp/0000000004" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified) while reading upstream, client: 172.23.66.69, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico", host: "vi-dvw70765", referrer: "http://vi-dvw70765/checksplunk/13"
2017/04/21 11:48:04 [notice] 6732#6204: signal process started
2017/04/21 11:48:04 [emerg] 6352#528: CreateDirectory() "C:\nginx/data/nginx/cache" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified)
2017/04/21 11:48:12 [notice] 6512#2300: signal process started
2017/04/21 11:48:18 [emerg] 1492#6744: CreateDirectory() "C:\nginx/data/nginx/cache" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified)
2017/04/21 11:49:24 [emerg] 5168#2396: CreateDirectory() "C:\nginx/data/nginx/cache" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified)
2017/04/21 11:49:40 [notice] 6368#1732: signal process started
2017/04/21 11:49:40 [error] 6368#1732: CreateFile() "C:\nginx/logs/nginx.pid" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified)
2017/04/21 11:50:38 [notice] 3500#6476: signal process started
2017/04/21 11:50:38 [error] 3500#6476: CreateFile() "C:\nginx/logs/nginx.pid" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified)
2017/04/21 11:50:57 [emerg] 2980#5288: "proxy_cache" zone "my-cache" is unknown in C:\nginx/conf/nginx.conf:141
2017/04/21 11:51:46 [notice] 5872#6156: signal process started
```

I've searched online to fix this, but couldn't find a fix this issue.

Any help/solution is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A longshot, but have you tried using forward slashes in your path configs?

Comment: yeah, I did but same issue.

Comment: FWIW, using backslashes and escaping them works on my end. E.g. `c:\\nginx\\data\\nginx\\cache` . It might be unnecessary for non-special characters, but doesn't seem to hurt and is visually consistent.  You may also need to create the root directory manually.